# What does it mean an Apple implementation is deprecated while still being able to use it. Reasons not to use it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deprecated, glkit

I'm using GLKit's GLKView in one of my projects. As per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit/glkview?language=objc) it is deprecated. I can still use it in my app and it is fully functional (for what I want it to do) with latest iOS versions. I'm using it because of an older SDK that I'm using has good functionality for it. What are reasons not to use it anymore?

Comment: Another consideration is that deprecated functions and libraries may not receive significant or any updates. All of GLKit is deprecated as Apple intends to drop support for OpenGL on iOS in favour of Metal. On new hardware performance or functionality may well be better using a Metal than using OpenGL

Comment: When it is deprecated, it is likely a better implementation is available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is deprecated, that means they may remove it in future versions. If you continue to use it, your code may break next time you update the library.

They left it in despite being deprecated to give you an opportunity to switch to a new solution.

Answer (score 1):

A function being deprecated means that it is still supported for now, but they are planning on deleting it. Often times this is because there is other better ways to achieve the same. A reason to not use it anymore is because it will very probably be deleted eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it now,but maybe can't in the future.Such as `UIWebView` just like Apple said:

> Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs.

It's the same.